# Glide.js - Disable/Enable Prev/Next buttons

Tags: jquery, glidejs

Using [Glide.js](http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/) (here's the [documentation section](http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/docs.html#options)) I've been unable to make the Prev button disabled when the slideshow first loads, but then to enable it once the second slide has been loaded. All I need to do is cycle between 2 slides.

Same thing with the Next button but vice versa: Enabled at first, but disabled when second slide is loaded.

I've tried a few things:

```
beforeInit: function() {
    $(".prev").attr("disabled");
}
```

…but for some reason the attribute `disabled` isn't added.

```
beforeInit: function() {
    $(".prev").attr("disabled");
},
afterInit: function() {
    $(".prev").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

…but same result as first approach.

```
beforeInit: function() {
    $(".prev").toggleClass("disabled");
}
```

…but this just adds a class (it actually doesn't toggle it) and the button still works to load the previous slide.

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/ca8d29139b409914e0795d9772d75421

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If someone need jQuery free solution:

```js
function DisableControls(Glide, Components, Events) {
  const PREV_CONTROL_SELECTOR = "[data-glide-dir='<']";
  const NEXT_CONTROL_SELECTOR = "[data-glide-dir='>']";
  const component = {
    buildAfter() {
      this.prevBtn = Components.Html.root.querySelector(PREV_CONTROL_SELECTOR);
      this.nextBtn = Components.Html.root.querySelector(NEXT_CONTROL_SELECTOR);
    },
    handleDisable() {
      const perView = Glide.settings.perView;
      const slidesCount = Components.Html.slides.length;

      this.prevBtn.disabled = (Glide.index <= 0);
      this.nextBtn.disabled = (Glide.index >= slidesCount - perView);
    },
  };

  Events.on("build.after", function () {
    component.buildAfter();
    component.handleDisable();
  });
  Events.on("run.after", function () {
    component.handleDisable();
  });
  return component;
}
```

Use:

```js
new Glide('.glide').mount({ DisableControls: DisableControls })
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) documentation

> `.attr( attributeName )`
>   Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

A single parameter in  is used to "look up" the attribute. You need to supply a second parameter to change the attribute's setting.

> `.attr( attributeName, value )`
>   Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.

Change it to:

```
$(".prev").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Additionally, it would appear your CSS in the codepen isnt looking for the attribute "disabled" to apply any styling changes. So you can combine the techniques using:

```
$(".prev").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Ah! The `value`, since I like to use `disabled` instead of `disabled="disabled"` I am not complying with jQuery's spec. I was able finally to figure it out though, see my answer. Gave you an upvote. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I [found a jQuery plugin](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/298591) that allows me to use `toggleAttr();` just like doing `toggleClass();`. For a designer like me, this is a Godsend

This plugin combined with the `afterInit` and `afterTransition` options from Glide.js allowed me to switch between two slides and toggle the `disabled` attribute on the Prev and Next buttons.

In the CSS I targeted the disabled buttons with an attribute selector.

This is my jQuery script solution:

```
/*!
 * toggleAttr() jQuery plugin
 * @link http://github.com/mathiasbynens/toggleAttr-jQuery-Plugin
 * @description Used to toggle selected="selected", disabled="disabled", checked="checked" etc…
 * @author Mathias Bynens <http://mathiasbynens.be/>
 */
jQuery.fn.toggleAttr = function(attr) {
 return this.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.attr(attr) ? $this.removeAttr(attr) : $this.attr(attr, attr);
 });
};

//Glide
$("#Glide").glide({
  type: "slideshow",
  autoplay: false,
  animationDuration: 1000,
  hoverpause: true,
  autoheight: true,
  afterInit: function() {
    $(".prev").toggleAttr("disabled");
  },
  afterTransition: function() {
    $(".prev").toggleAttr("disabled");
    $(".next").toggleAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

The CSS using an attribute selector to target the disabled buttons:

```
[disabled] { background: red; }
```

Here's a working demo in CodePen: http://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/73ecc288b581d78332fc6e69017c7a54?editors=0010